# How can I access json data as variable inside my scaffold in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I access **var apiData = jsonDecode(response.body);**

inside  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold()

I want to use something like

```
if (apiData["studentEmail"] == "") { return const SignIn(); } else { return const Dashboard(); }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I suggest that you do the service operations in a separate class. I suggest you look at the service-repository pattern for this.

Bring your data from the api by creating the getApi method inside the service class.
For example,

```
class MyApi{
  final String _getApi =
      "https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q=USD_TRY,EUR_TRY&compact=ultra&apiKey=26cb9ffd85f9bee9c208";

  
  Future<StudentModel?> getDatas() async {
    var response = await Dio().get(_getApi);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return StudentModel.fromJson(response.data);
    } else {
      debugPrint('${response.statusCode} : ${response.data.toString()}');
      throw UnimplementedError();
    }
  }
}
```

After that, Using FutureBuilder, give the future property the method that brings the api to your api class. And now you can access your data with the builder's AsynSnapshot. You can easily access the data in the future method with the snapshot that FutureBuilder now gives you.

```
FutureBuilder<StudentModel>(
     future: MyApi.getDatas,
     builder: (context, AsynSnapshot asynSnapshot){
    // You can easily access the data in the future method with the 
    // snapshot that FutureBuilder now gives you.
     asynSnapshot.data.yourData;
       }

)
```